# Error 150 (net::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN): The server's certificate appears to be a forgery

Tags: certificates, web-browser, chrome

Can you tell me shortly how to fix this problem in Chrome?

> Error 150 (net::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN): The server's
>   certificate appears to be a forgery

Comment: dont worry i fixed it

Comment: you just have to dawnload a new version like i did here it is                                              http://dw.cbsi.com/redir?edId=3&siteId=4&oId=1770-20_4-0&ontId=20_4&spi=d7ae12367782e5639dd6f624463eaff0&lop=link&tag=tdw_dltext&ltype=dl_dlnow&pid=13425566&mfgId=78250&merId=78250&pguid=UnFu7goOYJIAAE@70MIAAAFN&ttag=tdw_dltext;2&ctype=dm;language&cval=NONE;en&destUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.cnet.com%2F3001-2356_4-10958228.html%3Fspi%3Dd7ae12367782e5639dd6f624463eaff0